# Spring security for just authorization, how to implement custom UserDetailsService and call it from login page

Tags: spring-security

I have a system that already has a class to authenticate and control access to pages that require authentication, now I need include the spring security in the project to control access to pages in accordance with the permissions of each user and also control access to certain system resources, such as a user permission to list records and does not have permission to delete records.
I'm trying to implement a customUserDetails but I dont know how to do my login page calls it.

My web.xml:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <display-name>Ultracar Web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--<context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
     <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Principal/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml            
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My spring-security:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="Principal/index*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Principal/*" access="permitAll"/>

        <form-login login-page="/Principal/index.xhtml"        
                             default-target-url="/"
                             authentication-failure-url="/"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetails" class="br.com.ultracar.ultracarweb.spring.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetails" />  
</authentication-manager>    

</beans:beans>
```

My Login page:

```
<h:head>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="../Images/logo_ultracar.png"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./../Principal/template_start.xhtml">            
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="container" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
                        <ui:include src="slider.xhtml"/>
                    </div>                       

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{MBControl.login}" required="true"
                                                     style="width: 100%;-moz-box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
                                                     box-shadow: none !important; -moz-border-radius: 0 !important; 
                                                     -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;"
                                                     requiredMessage="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('User_required')}"/>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <h:outputLabel style="color: #303030;" value="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Password')}:" />
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:password value="#{MBControl.senha}" required="true" id="txtSenha" styleClass="reset-style"
                                                    style="width: 100%;-moz-box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
                                                    box-shadow: none !important; -moz-border-radius: 0 !important; 
                                                    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;"
                                                    requiredMessage="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('password_required')}"/>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>

                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:commandLink id="btnLogin" styleClass="btn button-green" ajax="false" action="#{MBControl.login()}" 
                                                       update="frmLogin" value="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Login')}" style="border-radius: 0 !important;"/>
                                    </div>                                  
                                    <p:growl autoUpdate="true"/>
                                </div>                                    

                        </h:form>
                    </div>                        
                </div> 
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

My login class:

```
public String login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Session session = FacesContextUtil.getRequestSession();
    Usuario user = null;
    boolean passwordOk = false;
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    try
    {
        user = (user) session.createCriteria(User.class)
                                                          .add(Restrictions.eq("user",login))
                                                          .list().get(0);
        senhaOk = (usuario.getPassword().equals(password));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }

    if (user !=null && passwordOk){
        if (!user.getActive()){
            warning(null,Utils.getStrLanguage("User_not_active")+"!",FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
            return "exit";
        }
        sessao.setAttribute("login", login);
        sessao.setAttribute("password", new Utils().SHA1(password));
        MBControl.matriz = usuario.getIdMatrix();
        userDetails.loadUserByUsername(login);

        return "sucess";
    }else{
        warning(null,Utils.getStrLanguage("User_pass_invalid")+"!",FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL);
        return "exit";
    }
}
```

Update, I am trying to implement (just for a test) UserDetailsServiceImpl this way:

```
@Service("userService")  
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {  

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username ) throws UsernameNotFoundException{  


        FacesContext contexto = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) contexto.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        boolean enabled = false;  
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = false;  
        boolean accountNonExpired = false;  
        boolean accountNonLocked = false;
        Authority autorizacao = new Authority("ROLE_ADMIN");   

        Set<Authority> roles = new HashSet<Authority>();
        enabled = true;  
        credentialsNonExpired = true;  
        accountNonExpired = true;  
        accountNonLocked = true;
        roles.add(autorizacao);
        String senha = session.getAttribute("password").toString(); 

        User springUser = new User(username, senha, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, roles);

        return springUser;   
    }

}
```

How to implement CustomUserDetails and call it on the login page?

Comment: Can you post the code to UserDetailsServiceImpl?

Comment: Hi @John R, I updated the post, please have a look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have `UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsServiceImpl();`.  For things to work correctly, your UserDetailService needs to be a Spring bean.

Comment: <beans:bean id="customUserDetails" class="br.com.ultracar.ultracarweb.spring.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />   this is not enough?